# Got element by classname, onclick give new classes for two elements

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, event-handling

I have two elements. One of them I want to get by class. When the element is clicked I want to give new classes to both of the elements or when clicked again, remove the classes. Doesnt give any issues, the new class just doesnt show up.

EDIT:
**The rendered HTML and Child Themes functions.php are too long to post here, but they are in https://github.com/iidis/stackoverflow**

Hook in CodeSnippets (WordPress plugin to add snippets in hooks)

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>
<script></script>

<?php });
```

JavaScript

```
    // Runs before the elements are added to the DOM 
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

        // Another element I want to give new class when the element is clicked
        var anotherElement = document.getElementById("onlyonmobilesearch");
        
        // Finds elements with class "menu-toggle", makes a NodeList. 
        // Gives eventlistener for every element on the list.

        document.querySelectorAll(".menu-toggle")
        .forEach((element) =>
        element.addEventListener("click", function(){

            // When clicked, if element does not have the wanted class already, 
            // give classes for both elements.
             if ( !element.classList.contains("teststyle") ) {
                     element.classList.add("teststyle");
                    anotherElement.classList.add("teststyle2");
                
            // If has the class, removes the class
            } else {
              element.classList.remove("teststyle");
                anotherElement.classList.remove("teststyle2");
              } }                       
        ));
});
```

CSS

```
.teststyle{
  color: red;
background:red;
}
    
.teststyle2 {
  color: black;
background:black;
}
```

Rendered HTML (if I understood rendering right). From source code of my page I took things that look important for me in this issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fi">
<head>
// here goes all metainfo I wont write here

// Loads stylesheets, for example these ones

<link rel='stylesheet' id='generate-child-css' href='http://...' media='all' />
<style id='generate-navigation-branding-inline-css'>
@media (max-width: 1024px){.site-header, #site-navigation, #sticky-navigation{display:none !important;opacity:0.0;}#mobile-header{display:block !important;width:100% !important;}#mobile-header .main-nav > ul{display:none;}#mobile-header.toggled .main-nav > ul, #mobile-header .menu-toggle, #mobile-header .mobile-bar-items{display:block;}#mobile-header .main-nav{-ms-flex:0 0 100%;flex:0 0 100%;-webkit-box-ordinal-group:5;-ms-flex-order:4;order:4;}}.main-navigation.has-branding .inside-navigation.grid-container, .main-navigation.has-branding.grid-container .inside-navigation:not(.grid-container){padding:0px 40px 0px 60px;}.main-navigation.has-branding:not(.grid-container) .inside-navigation:not(.grid-container) .navigation-branding{margin-left:10px;}.navigation-branding img, .site-logo.mobile-header-logo img{height:60px;width:auto;}.navigation-branding .main-title{line-height:60px;}@media (max-width: 1024px){.main-navigation.has-branding.nav-align-center .menu-bar-items, .main-navigation.has-sticky-branding.navigation-stick.nav-align-center .menu-bar-items{margin-left:auto;}.navigation-branding{margin-right:auto;margin-left:10px;}.navigation-branding .main-title, .mobile-header-navigation .site-logo{margin-left:10px;}.main-navigation.has-branding .inside-navigation.grid-container{padding:0px;}.navigation-branding img, .site-logo.mobile-header-logo{height:65px;}.navigation-branding .main-title{line-height:65px;}}
</style>

<script>

<style>

//some styles for "Other Element"

 .mobilesearch { // styles }
    
.toggled .inside-navigation #onlyonmobilesearch.mobilesearch { // styles }
    
#onlyonmobilesearch.mobilesearch > label > input { // styles }
    
.search-submit-mobile { //styles }

.search-submit-mobile:hover, .search-submit-mobile:focus, .search-submit-mobile:active{ // styles }

@media(min-width:1024px){ #onlyonmobilesearch{display:none;}
}

</style>

// Here I got JavaScript written above.

 </script>

</script>
<style> 
// Here I fot CSS written above
   </style>
<script>

( function() {function wpforms_js_error_loading() { if ( typeof window.wpforms !== 'undefined' ) {return;}var forms = document.querySelectorAll( '.wpforms-form' );if ( ! forms.length ) {return;} 
var error = document.createElement( 'div' );
error.classList.add( 'wpforms-error-container' );error.innerHTML = 'Heads up! WPForms has detected an issue with JavaScript on this page. JavaScript is required for this form to work properly, so this form may not work as expected. See our <a href="https://wpforms.com/docs/getting-support-wpforms/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">troubleshooting guide</a> to learn more or contact support.<p>This message is only displayed to site administrators.</p>';

                    forms.forEach(function(form){if ( ! form.querySelector( '.wpforms-error-container' ) ) {form.insertBefore( error.cloneNode( true ), form.firstChild );}} );};
if ( document.readyState === 'loading' ) {
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', wpforms_js_error_loading );} else {wpforms_js_error_loading();}}() );

</head>

<body>

</ul></div><div class="menu-bar-items"><style>
// some styles for "Another Element"

.toggled .inside-navigation #onlyonmobilesearch.mobilesearch {//styles}

#onlyonmobilesearch.mobilesearch > label > input {//styles}
</style>

<form id="onlyonmobilesearch" method="get" class="mobilesearch" action="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/"><span id="hakuteksti" aria-hidden="true">Hae sivustolta:</span>

/////////////////////////////////////
//for some reason this one is douple!!
/////////////////////////////////////

</ul></div><div class="menu-bar-items"><style>
// some styles for "Another Element"

.toggled .inside-navigation #onlyonmobilesearch.mobilesearch {//styles}

#onlyonmobilesearch.mobilesearch > label > input {//styles}
</style>

<form id="onlyonmobilesearch" method="get" class="mobilesearch" action="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/"><span id="hakuteksti" aria-hidden="true">Hae sivustolta:</span>

</body>
```

So, basically I added an eventlistener to run in DOM. Then I got "the another element" by ID. I made a NodeList with elements with my wanted class. Then I gave eventlisteners to all the elements in the list. I made onclick function that gives new class if it does not exist, removes if it already does.

Any clue, why this one is not working? (It is made for WordPress Code Snippet.)

Comment: Please edit your question and include the ***rendered*** HTML, CSS, and JavaScript so we can fully test your code.

Comment: After your edit, you still haven't added the relevant HTML. We need ***all*** the relevant code to be able to assist you.

Comment: Sorry I am not native English speaker, also inexperienced with coding. I tried to Google what is rendered HTML but doesnt get it but will try tomorrow. I also realised this one works with the "Element", only "Another Element" is not working.

Comment: I quickly pulled your JavaScript code into a codepen and used a simple sequence of HTML elements to test out your stuff. Frankly, the code seems to work the way it suggests it should. Classes appear for `#onlyonmobilesearch`, when any `.menu-toggle` is clicked and the `.menu-toggle` receives the `.teststyle` class. When clicked again, colors from both `#onlyonmobilesearch` and `.menu-toggle` are removed.

Most likely, your HTML is the issue. Either that, or you need to explain better how you want your implementation to work.

https://codepen.io/FarizF/pen/rNjRKra

Comment: It just means that we need to you look at the code that is sent to your browser and include the HTML portion.

Comment: Another possibility would be that you're not including the js correctly through Wordpress. Did you properly enqueue the scripts in your functions.php? https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/ Another way to test your code is to simply move that javascript into the `<script>` tag shown in your edit. Provided that your elements have the correct classes and id's, your code should simply work.

Comment: Thank you, looks like you are right and this piece of code is actually working and the problem is elsewhere. I added rendered HTML but might be that I added some wrong stuff, not sure.

Comment: Hi, idz. For the sake of being able to formally answer your question, please add this "rendered HTML" you mention. Maybe throw your functions.php into an edit of your question as well.

Comment: Hi Fariz Fakkel, thank you for the advide. Do you mean the whole long HTML source. code from my page?  They are too long to post here, I editet my question with a link to  https://github.com/iidis/stackoverflow where I posted them. Hope they are the right files needed.

Comment: First element works when I put !important to the CSS part. anotherElement is nested one so maybe that is the clue.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this one works. I got both elements by class instead of an id. In HTML another one of the elements shows twice so there might be something wrong.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>

  <script>
      
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

      document.querySelectorAll(".menu-toggle")
  .forEach((element) =>
        element.addEventListener("click", function()

            { if ( !element.classList.contains("teststyle") ) {
                     element.classList.add("teststyle");
                     
                     document.querySelectorAll(".mobilesearch")
                    .forEach((element2) =>
                      element2.classList.add("teststyle2") );
                
            } else {
              element.classList.remove("teststyle");
              
                     document.querySelectorAll(".mobilesearch")
                    .forEach((element2) =>
                      element2.classList.remove("teststyle2") );
              } }                                    
        ));
}); 

</script>
```